# Error at build.gradle android after adding target jvm

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, jvm

I receive such error:

```
Duplicate class com.tinder.scarlet.Deserialization found in modules jetified-scarlet-core-0.1.10.jar (com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-core:0.1.10) and jetified-scarlet-core-0.1.10.jar (com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-core:0.1.10)
```

I started receiving this error after adding these lines:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

to my `android` scopes at `build.gradle`. All these actions were made for solving this problem:

```
Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6
```

This problem I saw at this line:

```
val myService = scarlet.create<MessageService>() // word create was highlighted
```

My gradle implementations:

```
implementation 'com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.10'
implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-message-adapter-moshi:0.1.10'
implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-stream-adapter-rxjava2:0.1.10'
implementation 'com.github.tinder.scarlet:scarlet-websocket-okhttp:0.1.10'
```

Maybe I solved this problem in a wrong way and I have to use another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Duplicate class com.tinder.scarlet.Deserialization found in modules
>   jetified-scarlet-core

Kindly change version

```
implementation 'com.tinder.scarlet:scarlet:0.1.9' // or 0.1.7
```

Read **[Duplicate dependency compilation error](https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/issues/96)**.

Comment: so I have to downgrade my implementations?

Comment: @Andrew you can try.

Comment: but I receive such new error - `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.tinder.scarlet:websocket-okhttp:0.1.7` after downgrading to your versions

Comment: on the other hand when I use all libs with latest versions I receive such error - `Duplicate class kotlin.reflect.KClasses found in modules jetified-kotlin-reflect-1.1.1.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.1) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.3.70.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.70)
` :(

Comment: `implementation "com.tinder.scarlet:websocket-okhttp:0.1.9"`

Comment: check https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/issues/96#issuecomment-532876176

Comment: I tried this solution also) I saw all comments at this thread when you had posted your answer

Comment: @Andrew 
Adding implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version" solves the above error for me. Please try and let me know if this works for you?